# How do I define methods outside of the declaration for my specialization of a non-type template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The title is a mouthful, but basically I wrote something like this:

```
enum EnumType{ValA, ValB};

template<EnumType> class A {};

template<>
class A<ValA>
{
private:
    double param;
public:
    A(double param);
};

template<>
A<ValA>::A(double param)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

and when I try to compile it I get:

> error: template-id 'A<>' for 'A<(EnumType)0u>::A(double)' does not
>   match any template declaration

Am I doing this wrong?

After searching online for similar cases, I tried to remove `template<>` (even though I don't understand why this would work), but then I get

> multiple definition of 'A<(EnumType)0u>::A(double)'

I guess that I can replace `template<>` by `inline` (I tried and it compiles), but that doesn't feel like the proper way to do it (or if it is, I don't understand why).

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with what I wrote, why changing this seems to work, and what's the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me what is wrong with what I wrote, why changing this seems to work, and what's the proper way to do it ?

The standard says:

> Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the template<> syntax.

Therefore, in your case you must use:

```
A<EnumType::ValA>::A(double param)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

No `template<>` at all is just fine. That's because you are actually specializing a (special) member function (the constructor) of an explicitly specialized class template.
See it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2159ebcc1f5af847).

---

It would have been different if no explicit specialization was given.
As a minimal working example:

```
enum EnumType{ValA, ValB};

template<EnumType> class A
{
private:
    double param;
public:
    A(double param);
};

template<>
A<EnumType::ValA>::A(double)
{
    // Do Stuff
}

int main() {
    A<EnumType::ValA> a{0.};
}
```

In this case, `template<>` is required before the definition of the constructor because you are not defining a specialization of a member function of an already specialized class template.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semicolon (;) at the the end of class definition.
And the non template member function can be defined this way:

```
A<ValA>::A(double param) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Informally, the template parameter list is only written when necessary, for example, for defining a member function template of a class template, the two template parameter list should all be written

```
template<class U, class V>
class A{
  template <class T>
  A();
};

template<class U, class V>
template <class T>
A<U, V>::A() {}
```

and a empty template parameter list is needed for a explicit specialisation of function template (which, i guess, is the reason why you use so here), informally because it tells the compiler that this is not a function overloading.

Comment: I would you create an instance of a class from the second snippet exactly? Moreover, the problem isn't the fact that it is not a member template function.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the missing semicolon (but that's only a typo I made in the post and not something preent in my actual code)